# Where to set additional query parameters for tree lazy load expand requests with JsonRestStore in Dojo?

Tags: parameters, dojo, tree, lazy-loading

For a lazy loaded tree using JsonRestStore and ForestModel, where
would I set an additional query parameter to be included in expand
requests?  I have declared the additional parameters in the SMD, but I
can only seem to use the default values set in the SMD instantiation,
since expand events only pass the node id to the Service.js's
"_executeMethod".

I've stepped through a bunch of times, but there is some magic that
happens in a dojo._hitchArgs method in between the Service.js
_executeMethod that makes the request and the JsonRest.js
query(service, id, **args**) method.  So basically how do I get my parameters in
that **args** variable?

Thanks,
-robbie

Comment: For example, my implementation has two lazy loaded trees on a page, which hit the same service target. I need to pass a 'treeType' parameter along with the nodeId to get nodes for the correct tree from the service. If I declare this parameter and set a default in the SMD, all works well for one tree.  But to get more than one tree on a page I need to create a separate service in the SMD for each, with a different serviceName, so that I can set a different default value... I'm sure there must be a better way.